# Has any mathematical analysis of The Resistance been done?

Tags: the-resistance

I played The Resistance for the first time a couple weeks ago and am interested in writing a simulation program to test strategies. I know that [mathematical analysis has been done](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609534) on Mafia proper, but does anyone know of work that has been done to analyze The Resistance?

Comment: Do you have a link to the Mafia analysis?

Comment: I've read this one : http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609534 but there are others on arxiv.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a mathematical analysis of a potential winning strategy for the Resistance side: http://amininima.wordpress.com/2013/05/18/the-resistance/

And there's a thread on Boardgamegeek where they're trying to determine a formula for "spy-ness": http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/759016/using-excel-to-find-spies

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Huh. So the tl;dr is: she proposes a strategy *(for a game of mutually-acknowledged perfectly-intelligent logicians with no Tells)* that gives Resistance **a mere 26.6̅% chance of victory** in 6-player game — am I reading that right? With the acknowledged lack of optimality proof, I wonder if (and, if so, how far) that could be improved.